# How to save csv file into a specific path?

Tags: python, csv

Recently, i had a project is to save some data as a csv file and save it in the absolute path.
Here is my code.

```
import csv
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
with open("C:/test.csv","w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(a)
```

but it shows some error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rickchen/Desktop/save1.py", line 3, in <module>
    with open("C:/test.csv","w") as f:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/test.csv'
```

Can any master help me? Thank you very much ^_^

Comment: any master or non-master could tell you that you're not using Windows 3.1: you cannot write to root of C drive unless you have elevated privileges. This isn't a python problem

Comment: Non-master speaking here. You don't have write permission for that directory. Use a different one.

Comment: How to write permission?

Comment: Depends if you have permission to change permissions (I'm guessing this belongs to school/work etc.). Go to C drive, right click, properties, security. See if you're able to add write access for your user.

Answer (score 1):

You possibly don't have write permission to write to the root of your C drive. You have a few alternatives to try:

1. Run Python with Administrator privileges. This obviously depends on how you are running your script. For example, if you are starting a command prompt and running the script in that, right click on it and select "Run as Administrator".
2. Use Windows to give your user account write access to your `C:\` root folder.
3. Possibly make sure the output file is not already open in another application.
4. Ideally you should write to a more suitable folder. It is straight forward for example to write the output either to your `Desktop`, or to your `Documents` folder.

Your script could be updated as follows:

```
import csv
import os

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

filename = os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEDRIVE"], os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop", "test.csv")

with open(filename, "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(a)  # Or use writer.writerows([row] for row in a) for one per line
```

`os.environ["HOMEDRIVE"]` and `os.environ["HOMEPATH"]` would give your user's home folder, adding either `Desktop` or `Documents` would give you a suitable path. `os.path.join()` is used to safely join the various bits together with suitable separators giving you a filename such as:

```
C:\Users\Fred\Desktop\test.csv
```

This assumes you are using Python 2.x

---

If you are using Python 3.x, you would just need to modify how the file is opened for use with the CSV writer:

```
with open(filename, "w", newline="") as f:
```